# QT "MainWindow" is not initialized using here

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm new in qt&c++ and trying to make a window that positioning itself in the screen's center

there is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
    QApplication App(argc, argv);
    MainWindow *MainWindow;
    
    MainWindow->setFixedSize(854, 480);
    MainWindow->move((desktop->width() - 854)/2,(desktop->height() - 480)/2);

    MainWindow->show();
    return App.exec(); 
}
```

In qt creator i get warning in `MainWindow->setFixedSize(854, 480);` that says

`Variable "MainWindow" is uninitialized when used here` 
and
`Called c++ object pointer is uninitialized`

what i supposed to do?

Comment: The opposite of "uninitialized" is "initialized". The warning is "Variable 'MainWindow' is uninitialized"; the opposite of that situation would be if the variable 'MainWindow' is **initialized**. Now take a guess -- what needs to happen to the variable `MainWindow`?

Comment: you should create mainwindow first `MainWindow *m_MainWindow=new MainWindow();`

Comment: Note that the question-as-asked would likely have a (distinct, and more useful) follow-up question regarding to *what* `MainWindow` should be initialized. This follow-up question would not need to refer to the warning; instead it should describe what you intend `MainWindow` to represent in your code. It might also help to explain why it is a pointer, and why it is leaked (if the leaking was intentional/known). A different focus to get more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a pointer to `MainWindow` which is simply a memory address (no MainWindow has actually been allocated in memory yet). To create an instance of `MainWindow`, use `MainWindow *window = new MainWindow();`
or
simply don't make it a pointer and use "." access instead of "->" access:

```
MainWindow window;
window.setFixedSize(854, 480);
```

p.s. You cannot make a variable that has the same exact name as a class. You gotta mix up the upper/lowercase letters at least